# What does CRP decreased result means within 2 months

Tags: infection, blood-tests, crp-c-reactive-protein

What does it means when you repeat all your blood test between 2 months and all the result are within range and exactly the same as previously, but a test called CRP decreased from 2 to 0.98.

Does it mean that I have infection or not ?

Comment: Look at that question's answer, it talks about CRP.  Please remember we can't give medical advice, also.

Answer (score 0):

CRP is sometimes used as a marker of infection or inflammation, yes, but (1) it's nonspecific and (2) to say an infection is present or absent requires a LOT more information and most often a clinical examination.  By itself without any clinical context those values don't tell us nearly enough to comment.

Ask whomever ordered the test, they're the ones evaluating you, and obviously doing so for a reason.  We can't give medical advice here on SE.